# How to integrate Square Payment in my website?

Tags: transactions, square

I want to integrate Square API in my website for payments of my products. Please provide my some solution so that I can integrate it.

I am beginner in Square API and searched a lot of things about it but could not found any way to integrate it. Please give me some answers if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples for examples on using the Square APIs in a few languages. Hope that helps!